# Chrome element.style cutting off images

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, developer-tools

As you can notice in the picture Chrome is sizing the height of the selected div to 55px. This is element.style which I think is calculated by a script and inserted into the html. 55px is not correct because it is cutting off the images so I want to make it 305px. The weird thing is, is that this ONLY happens in Chrome and works on IE and Firefox. Plus it doesn't happen when I am working on the html page locally in Chrome on my computer. I tried to override the 55px CSS rule by using !important but this doesn't do anything. I cleared my browser cache/cookies and re-uploaded the files but nothing. Chrome seems to correct itself and display is correctly when you make the browser window small then full screen again. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the whole code or give a link to the site?

Comment: ambrite.ca is the website. You might have to refresh the page. The issue happens ~90% of the time.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on FF.  I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function`.  I would move your main.js script to load after nicescroll.js.  Maybe that error is mucking things up.

Comment: Actually the problem is that isotope is trying to adjust the height of the dom-objects, before the images has been loaded. See solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the */js/main.js* file

Change this code:

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotopeItem',
    resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: $container.width() / $resize
    }
});
```

To:

```
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.isotopeItem',
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: $container.width() / $resize
        }
    });
});
```

This will hopefully make isotope wait for images to load.

**EDIT:** Imagesloaded is no longer included in the newest versions of isotope. You got an older version with Imagesloaded included, but if you were to upgrade to a newer version, you will have to use this one: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: This works great and I love the new animation, thanks!